# Must replace text in Visual Studio itself

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I need a way to replace some lines in code itself.

I recently changed one of my voids, earlier it was accepting MediaElements, and now it gets usual strings instead.

Now, I must change all lines, of similar structure:

```
AssignPathVoice(vcoSomething);
```

To this:

```
AssignPathVoice("vcoSomething");
```

Yes, of course I tried to google on that issue, and even got links to articles about regular expressions, but shame to admit, I still don't understand what expressions to use in my specific case.

I'll try to summarize:

This part: AssignPathVoice(

Changed to: AssignPathVoice("

And

This part: );

Changed to: ");

And whatever is between those two strings must be left untouched.

What regular expression I should use in this specific case, and how before and after fields in replace must be designed?

Can this be done by Quick Replace or Replace in Files?

Comment: Try `(AssignPathVoice\()(\w+)\);` and replace with `$1"$2");`

Comment: That worked great, thank you! Please, submit it as answer, so I could close question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

**Find**: `(AssignPathVoice\()(\w+)\);` 
**Replace with**: `$1"$2");`

Note that you may add a word boundary at the start to make sure `AssignPathVoice` is matched as a whole word.

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(AssignPathVoice\()` - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` backreference):
- `(\w+)` - Group 2 (later referred to with `$2` backreference): one or more letters, digits or/and `_`
- `\);` - a `);` sequence of chars.